# Gecko+xulrunner cannot display some websites properly

Tags: .net, gecko, xulrunner

I am using Skybound.GeckoFX.v1.9.1.0 + xulrunner-1.9.1.2.en-US.win32. When I browse some website like "www.apple.com", it cannot be display properly, and I guess it should be caused by javascript error. I was wondering if someone has also faced this issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is a very old version. You can find the only actively developed fork here: https://bitbucket.org/geckofx
It's now only called GeckoFX.